# Android MVVM sample architecture project required

Tags: android, mvvm, project, directory-structure

I am new to android MVVM architecture. Can I get any sample project from where I can follow folder structure for the implementation. I want to call REST Apis from the app. But I didn't find any good sample. Please let me know any good projects ti refer (Apart from google samples)

Comment: Here you are: https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+MVVM+sample+architecture+project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others mentioned, Google would be the first place to search this kind of stuff. As you mentioned, there are MVVM samples provided by Google on GitHub. However, they are a bit complicated to understand due to the project being really large. I believe this that this sample project is much easier to understand and does a good job explaining MVVM: https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1.

Hopefully this helps!